# Excel: What is the difference between the "Page Setup" Dialog and the contextual tab "Design?"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was trying to study for Microsoft Office Specialist, because I have a specific job in mind that would appreciate that.

That being said, one of the tutorials I was following had us go to the "insert" tab and select "header and footer."

However, whenever I do this, I get the "Page Setup" dialog, and the appropriate tab.  In the video, they get a "Design" tab.

What factors control this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly a different version of Excel?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator My version is "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016."  (Free through work.)  Could there be that much variation between the 2016's?

Comment: you haven't said what version is being used in the tutorial. A screen shot of the two would be helpful.

Comment: Allright, what I've come to is this: if I open a new workbook, I get the design tab as normal.  However, certain OTHER worksheets seem to give me the dialog.   So it seems to depend on the worksheet

Comment: Perhaps the other workbooks are in Compatibility Mode? Look in the title bar when you have the wb OP open.

Comment: Nothing seems to say "compatibility," though to be fair, I'm not sure what the workbook OP stands for.. there is no loss if I upload a copy.

Comment: Sorry, auto-correct...I meant *look in the title bar when you have the workbook open.* It will say `[Compatibility Mode]` to the right of the workbook title if it's in said mode.

Comment: It does not appear to be in compatibility mode.  It's a good thought, though?

Comment: Time for screen shots! And versions!

Answer (score 0):

'INSERT' and 'PAGE LAYOUT' tabs are different then each other.

INSERT tab has commands like Pivot Table, Table, Chart, Hyperlink **but not the Header & Footer.**

*Header & Footer belongs to the PAGE LAYOUT tab.*

You can navigate through **Page Layout, Margin, Custom Margin** then you get **'Page Setup'** tab.

Which has commands related to,

- Page Orientation & Size.
- Margins including Header & Footer Margins.
- Header & Footer Message settings.
- And the last one is Sheet.

Therefore, if you are looking to handle *Header & Footer Messages along with their Margins* and their position on the page then better hit the PAGE LAYOUT.

*I hope this help you.*